# Java smack / Android asmack RosterListener

Tags: java, android, listener, smack

I've been searching alot. but couldn't find anything. I need to refresh state of the contacts with rosterlistener. (offline/online). WHen creating roster i do:

```
Presence presence = roster.getPresence(r.getUser());
                if(presence.isAvailable()){
                    userstatus.add("online");
                }else{
                    userstatus.add("offline");
                }
```

userstatus is a vector string, then i make a string array from it. In my main program i just check this stirng array for the offline or online. But what to do if user goes offline/online. WHere exactly i must put the listener and how exactly to use it?

Answer (score 6):

You implement a `RosterListener` and make use of the [`presenceChanged()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.1.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/RosterListener.html#presenceChanged%28org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence%29) method. Here's sample code exactly as it appears in the [Smack documentation](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/roster.html).

```
Roster roster = con.getRoster();
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
    // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
        System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom() + " " + presence);
    }
});
```

Note that the JavaDoc suggests not using the presence received in the change event but checking for the best presence available each time:

> To get the current "best presence" for a user after the presence update, query the roster:

```
String user = presence.getFrom();
Presence bestPresence = roster.getPresence(user);
```

> That will return the presence value for the user with the highest priority and availability.